# Submenus slide up too much as the window scroll down

Tags: css, joomla3.0

I have a website which was built with Joomla. The website has a main menu with submenus. As the window is scrolled down a little bit, the submenus slide upwards more than expected as shown in the following picture (the wrong appearance).

[image: problem is shown here]

the menu when the window is not scrolled down looks like the following (the correct appearance):

[image]

What could be the problem? where should I modify the configuration or the code?

here is some part of the css/s5_flex_menu.css. I hope it will help:

```
    /* all menu links */
#s5_nav a, #subMenusContainer a{
        text-decoration:none;
}

/* Just main menu links --[for non-javascript users this applies to submenu links as well]*/
#s5_nav a{
        margin:0;
}

#subMenusContainer ul li {
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
}

/* Just sub menu links */
#subMenusContainer a, #s5_nav li li a{
        text-align:left;
        font-size:0.9em;
        width:auto;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        color:#ffffff;
        white-space: pre;
}

#subMenusContainer a:after, #s5_nav li li a:after {
content:"\a";
}

/* ----[ OLs ULs, LIs, and DIVs ]----*/


/* All ULs and OLs */
#nav, #s5_nav ul, #s5_nav ol, #subMenusContainer ul, #subMenusContainer ol {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
        line-height: 1em;
}

/* All submenu OLs and ULs */
#s5_nav ol, #s5_nav ul, #subMenusContainer ul, #subMenusContainer ol {
        left:0;
}

#subMenusContainer img {
margin-right:8px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: where exactly from the code? because the code is huge

Comment: Isolate only what is the problem

Comment: is the code that I show is enough? @romuleald

Comment: Do you have any fixed element? Could you show the image with and without the problem?